# How to deny/restrict access to a particular file type in a LAMP environment?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, lamp

I have a page where users can listen to some songs, the songs are played with JavaScript so if you look at the page source you would see the full path to the songs and users can just download the song.

How can I deny access to those songs (.mp3) to everyone trying to access that file except for the JavaScript code on my page accessing it?

Comment: You could try to fool around with HTTP fields like HTTP_REFERER or HTTP_USER_AGENT: the JS could request the mp3 saying something, and the server would serve the music only if it has that information. The end user could still easily fool the system, as he can extract that information from the JS, but it'd make him more annoyed. Then again, you can't, ever, make it impossible for the user to get the file: if it's playing on his computer, he can get it. It's easier for everybody if you actually allow the user to download the file if he wants to.

Comment: Or store the files outside of the web root, and write a server side utility to fetch and return the mp3 through an ajax request.  Also set the permissions lower i.e. chmod 555 *.mp3

Answer (score 2):

As JavaScript is executed on the client, and you need it to be able to download the mp3, your clients already essentially *have* the mp3 -- in their browser download cache folders.

You are probably better off encrypting the JavaScript or dynamically loading it afterwards. Nonetheless, if a client has somewhat of a knowledge about how it all works, he will still find the MP3.

Your only real option would be a new plugin for the browsers that plays the file you encrypted somehow.

If you deny access to `*.mp3` files, your JavaScript will not be able to play the file, too.